# How to import canvas.draw object into a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I do not need the `setcontentview()` method. Tell me another one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need setContentView(). There are two types--one that takes a resource ID and one that takes a View object (and, optionally, a LayoutParams object). Those are the only practical ways to add content to your activity. You cannot draw directly from the activity; you have to use a View of some sort. You can create your own custom view as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).